# An exercise in the first edition of Serge Lang's 'Linear Algebra.' What does this exercise mean? I cannot understand it at all?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, tensor-products

I am currently reading the Japanese translation of the first edition of Serge Lang's 'Linear Algebra.'

The following exercise is in this book:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $K$.
> Let $A:V\to V$ be a linear mapping.
> Show that there is a unique linear mapping $F:V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$ such that $F(v\otimes w)=Av\otimes Aw$.

I cannot understand this exercise at all.
$F$ is a mapping from $V\otimes V$ to $V\otimes V$ such that $F(v\otimes w)=Av\otimes Aw$.
So, the uniqueness is obvious.

Does this exercise mean the following?

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space on $K$.
> Let $A:V\to V$ be a linear mapping.
> Show that a mapping $F:V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$ such that $F(v\otimes w)=Av\otimes Aw$ is linear.

Comment: Think, what are elements of $V\otimes V$ besides decomposable tensors of the form $v\otimes w$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you very much for your answer. I thought $V\otimes V=\{v\otimes w:v\in V, w\in W\}$.

Comment: You were mistaken. Check your book again.

Comment: Not only are there elements of $ V \otimes V $ that are not of the form $ v \otimes w $ (so it's not immediate that such a map must be unique), a single element can also be written in that form in more than one way (so it's not immediate that such a map must exist); that is, you can have $ v _ 1 \otimes w _ 1 = v _ 2 \otimes w _ 2 $ without $ v _ 1 = v _ 2 $ and $ w _ 1 = w _ 2 $ (because $ ( k v ) \otimes w = v \otimes ( k w ) $).

Comment: But when you really grasp tensor products, then this *will* be obvious, because a linear map from $ V \otimes V $ is the same thing as a bilinear map from $ V \times V $ (which really is $ \{ ( v , w ) : v \in V , w \in V \} $).  So you just have to check that $ A ( k v ) \otimes A w = k ( A v \otimes A w ) $, $ A v \otimes A ( k w ) = k ( A v \otimes A w ) $, $ A ( v _ 1 + v _ 2 ) \otimes A w = ( A v _ 1 \otimes A w ) + ( A v _ 2 \otimes A w ) $, and $ A v \otimes A ( w _ 1 + w _ 2 ) = ( A v \otimes A w _ 1 ) + ( A v \otimes A w _ 2 ) $.

Comment: @TobyBartels thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Lang proved the following theorem:

> Theorem 1
> Let $V,W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $K$.
> There exist a finite dimensional vector space $T$ and a bilinear mapping $V\times W\to T$ which satisfy the following TP1 and TP2.
>
> TP1:
> Let $U$ be a vector space over $K$ and $g:V\times W\to U$ be a bilinear mapping.
> There is a unique linear mapping $g_*:T\to U$ such that $g(v,w)=g_*(v\otimes w)$ for any $v\in V$ and $w\in W$.
>
> TP2:
> Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ be a basis of $W$.
> $v_i\otimes w_j$ is a basis of $T$.
>
> We write $T=V\otimes W$.

I will use this theorem to solve the exercise.

Let $g:V\times V\to V\otimes V$ be a mapping such that $g:(v,w)\mapsto Av\otimes Aw$.
Then, $g$ is bilinear since $A$ is linear and $\otimes$ is bilienar.
So, by Theorem 1 TP1, there is a unique linear mapping $g_*: V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$ such that $Av\otimes Aw=g_*(v\otimes w)$.
Let $F:=g_*$.